# Visual Studio does not launch on first install

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Several person reported having issues with the installation of Visual Studio 2017.15.3, where VS would not start.

When I would click on the launch button from the installer:

- The devenv.exe would start but the IDE would not show.

When I would click on Visual Studio from the Windows Start Menu:

- The devenv.exe would start but the IDE would not show.

When I would run devenv.exe as admin:

- The devenv.exe would start but the IDE would not show

Context:

- Brand new PC with Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Did you have a look in the event viewer?

Answer (score 0):

After spending much time figuring out what was the issue, I found that the link to visual studio had only read permissions.

To fix the issue, right click on the link to the devenv.exe that is published in the start menu and provide the rights to execute the application.

This took some time to find and wanted to avoid anyone to loose time with this. hope Microsoft Fixes this of the next versions.